# How To Resolve Error After Create File Pdf using ItextPdf

Tags: android, pdf, itext

Hello i have a problem i want to make a pdf file using coming from text i have learnit from itextpdf i have following all tutorial but still i dont know file is corrupted after success create file can someone help me please here is my code

```
                       OutputStream stream=new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/fileTest/cxz.pdf");
        Document document=new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,stream);
        document.open();
        document.addTitle("cxcxcxcx");
        document.addSubject("cxcxccx");
        document.addCreator("cxcxcxcx");
       document.add(new Paragraph("cxcxcxcx"));
        document.close();
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'

```
     try {
                String parsedText="";
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(yourPdfPath);
                int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
                for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
                    parsedText   = parsedText+PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i+1).trim()+"\n"; //Extracting the content from the different pages
                }
                System.out.println(parsedText);

        Document document=new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,parsedText);
        document.open();
        document.addTitle("FileName");
        document.addSubject("MyFile");
        document.addCreator("cxcxcxcx");
       document.add(new Paragraph("cxcxcxcx"));


                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question i want to ask is this for we read data first in pdf after that we write to file pdf again ?

Comment: OutputStream stream=new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/fileTest/cxz.pdf");
same thing you did here .

Comment: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-1

visit here for more detailed information.

Comment: @naufalsyarifuddin , Vote up or mark as correct if it solves your problem.